req.body is being empty
req.body is being empty for only /api/login and /api/signup but working fine for other routes.Checked everything, and everything looks good but still this. already used parsers as other routes are working fine. I have sent the req to /api/login from frontend using axios but it is returning missing fields.
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const User = require("./models/user.js");
const Image = require("./models/image.js");
const path = require("path");
const generateUniqueId = require('generate-unique-id');


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

async function connection() {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MBD_KEY);
}

connection()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("Connection with Database Succeded!")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })

app.post("/api/:id/upload", upload.array("images", 12), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { id } = req.params;
        let { manualLoc, capturedLoc } = req.body;

        let reportId=generateUniqueId({
            length:10,
            useLetter: false
        })

        if(!capturedLoc || capturedLoc.length===0){
            return res.status(400).send("Location turned Off")
        }

        if (!req.files) {
            res.status(400).send("no file uploaded");
            return;
        }
        for (file of req.files) {
            const imagePath = file.path;
            try {
                const image = new Image({
                    imagePath: imagePath,
                    uploadedBy: id,
                    manualLoc: manualLoc,
                    capturedLoc: capturedLoc,
                    reportId: reportId
                })
                await image.save();
                console.log("image uploaded");
            } catch (error) {
                fs.unlink(imagePath, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("failed to delete image from server, which image data failed to upload on mongoDB")
                    }
                    console.log("image deleted from server due to image data failed to upload on mongo db")

                })
                console.log(error.message);
                if(req.files.indexOf(file)==req.files.length-1){

                    return res.status(400).send("Image Upload Failed!")
                }
            }

        }
        return res.status(200).send("Images uploaded successfully!")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error in uploading Image!")
    }
})

app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let { email, password } = req.body ;
    if(!email || !password){
        return res.status(400).send("missing fields");
    }
    let validUser = await User.find({
        email: email.trim().toLowerCase(),
        password: password.trim(),
    })
    if (validUser.length != 0) {
        res.status(200).send(validUser[0]._id);
    }else{
        res.status(404).send("user not found!");
    }

})

app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { name, email, password } = req.body;
        if (!name || !email || !password) {
            res.status(400).send("Missing required Fields")
            return;
        }
        let newUser = new User({
            name: name.trim().toLowerCase(),
            email: email.trim().toLowerCase(),
            password: password.trim(),
        })
        newUser.save()
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        res.status(201).send("User Created!")
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("root working")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})


 const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();


        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login');
            setData(response.data);
            if(response.status==200){
                console.log(data)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setData(null); // Clear any previous data
            console.log(error)
        }



    }


It's not possible to tell it like this. Can you attach screenshot of payload, API call and the full api file as well?

What is the content-type of the request? Which middlewares do you have in your script?

You're sending multipart/form-data which is not handled by either express.json() or express.urlencoded(). Change the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Given Hoppscotch looks like a Postman clone, this should answer your question: Postman Chrome: What is the difference between form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded and raw.

it again not working when sending req from frontend using axios  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login');
        setData(response.data);
        if(response.status==200){
            console.log(data)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setData(null); // Clear any previous data
        console.log(error)
    }



}  @Phil


You seem to be missing the data part in your Axios request... axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', { email: 'me@example.com', password: 'password' })

Paste full examole of frontend code how you send request but not in comment, edit your post

You didn't send data in your request.
Please check the docs https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example .
You can see request payload in your browser netwrok tab after clicking submit button.
FE code should be like this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export function LoginForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/login', {
        email,
        password,
      });
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  if (data) {
    // just an example
    console.log(data);
    return <div>Logged In</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Form</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='Enter your email'
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            type='password'
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            placeholder='Enter your password'
          />
        </div>

        <button type='submit'>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}


yeah brother i have already used parser as i said in the question

Ok, I found an issue and edited my answer. Provide full FE code that you use in your Component

guys vote please
